# Button Text not aligned Safari

Tags: iphone, button, text, alignment, center

Could anyone inform me as to why this text is not centered? I swear the upload and download buttons are identical, also the subscribe kinda does the same thing..is the iphone just weird and I have to compensate for the non conformity? Thanks

Sorry for posting the wall of text, I would know how else one would be able to decipher this problem.

[image: Safari View]
**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Community Sound</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile_style.css">
</head>


<body>
  <!-- Headers -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="no-result vertical-align-outer">
      <div class="vertical-align">
        <h1 class="header">Sample pack Generator</h1>
        <p class="subheader">Having a creative block?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=" vertical-align-outer">
    <div class="vertical-align">
      <div class='center margin_bottom'>
        <button class='text-white button'>Upload</button>
        <button class='text-white button'>Download</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="no-result vertical-align-outer">
    <div class="vertical-align">
      <form action="phEmail.php" method="POST">
        <!-- EMAIL -->
        <div>
          <label for="email"></label>
          <input type="email" class="email glowing-border" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="emailbtn">Subscribe</button>
        <span></span>
        <!-- errors will go here -->
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="sub_result">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<footer>
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=5NenPKc4q2177ZpoquvHh8okRxZWSeSNw4aedlweOg4OZeMMN3bW78JCXEO&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8d64ad11bbf4d2a5a1a0d303a50933f9b2" target="_blank" STYLE="text-decoration:none; color: #ffc439;"
    class="text-white"> &nbsp; Donate</a> &nbsp;| &nbsp;
    <a href="about.html" STYLE="text-decoration:none" class="text-white">About</a> &nbsp;| &nbsp;    
    <a href="terms.html" STYLE="text-decoration:none" class="text-white">Terms</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
    <a href="contact.html" target="_blank" STYLE="text-decoration:none" class="text-white">  Contact</a> &nbsp;
  </p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css);

body {
   background: url(http://i.imgur.com/hyC6F3D.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: "gill sans";
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.header {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.subheader {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top:5%;
}

.no-result {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  color: #fff;

}

.vertical-align-outer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.vertical-align {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

footer {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
  text-align:center;
}

.text-white {
  font-family: "gill sans";
  color: white;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.button{
  color:white;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  margin:5%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-color:rgba(255,255, 255, 1);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 100ms linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: 100ms linear 0s;
  -o-transition: 100ms linear 0s;
  transition: 100ms linear 0s;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
}

.button:active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .50);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
}

.button:target {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .20);
  -webkit-transform: scale(100%);
}

.center{
  text-align: center;
}
.margin_bottom{
  margin:20px;
}





.email {
  height: 30px;
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #cacaca;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  margin:2%;
}

.glowing-border {
  border: 2px solid #dadada;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.glowing-border:focus {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  color: black;
  outline: none;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px #ffffff;
}



.emailbtn {
  height: 35px;
  width: 120px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 5%;
  color: #cacaca;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border: 2px solid #dadada;
  border-radius: 7px;
  outline: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
}

.emailbtn:active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .50);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  border-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #ffffff; 
}

.emailbtn:target {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .20);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Post is 2 years old now, but anyway:

`padding` can not be set to `auto` — it is not valid CSS — so the buttons *probably* have padding set elsewhere or are using the browser's default padding.

I would guess the padding is pushing the "Download" text to the right and the button is not wide enough to accommodate the padding and the text.

You could set `padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0` instead.

I can't exactly tell without seeing the dev tools so this is a best guess.